# CSS Transition not working - Using radio button as a show/hide

Tags: html, css

Hello everyone this may seem easy to many people, But I just don't get it why `transition` is not working when I click the radio button to show the hidden side nav. 
So I am creating a side nav using only html and css and I found out the I can use radio button as a way to show and hide content. I accomplished the show and hide part but then I decided to put a `transition` css so that after I click the show button it will not show instantly but with transition same goes with the hide/close button.

Below is my code snippet

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.nav {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 5s ease-in;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: white;
    
}
#show:checked ~ .nav {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 250px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
   -o-transition: all 1s linear;
   transition: all 1s linear;
}
#close:checked ~ .nav {
    display: none;
   background: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
   
   opacity: 0.7;
   -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
   -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
   -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
   -o-transition: all 1s linear;
   transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <input type="radio" name="side" id="show">show
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <input type="radio" name="side" id="close">close
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Task sheets</li>
                <li>Poftfolio</li>
                <li>Contacts</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no transition because you use `display: none;` on the element when it is hidden.

The element does not exist in the DOM when its display value is set to `none`.

When the checkbox gets checked, you give the `nav` a width of `250px` and add it to the DOM. But it is *added* like that, with a width of `250px`. Remove `display: none` from the `.nav` element and the transitions apply.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.header {
 transition: 2s ease-in-out all;
}
.nav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    padding-top: 60px;
    color: white;
    
}
#show:checked ~ .nav {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 250px;
}
#close:checked ~ .nav {
    display: none;
   background: rgb( 40, 44, 47 );
   
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <input type="radio" name="side" id="show">show
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <input type="radio" name="side" id="close">close
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Task sheets</li>
                <li>Poftfolio</li>
                <li>Contacts</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
```

Keep in mind that your HTML is not valid. `input` is not a valid child of `ul`, so the behavior may not be reliable. Check [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul).

Answer (score 1):

Its not really working because you're using `display` property which is not allowed to be animated.
Instead of doing so you can really create something with opacity, transform and etc.

Also to prevent dbl clicking you can use `pointer-events`. Here are the docs for it:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

I've created for you little code pen to really know whats happening.
https://codepen.io/snoh666/pen/VwKrbeR